# Let $p$ be Riemann integrable function with $p(x) \ge 0,$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. If $\int_{a}^{b} p(x)dx = 0,$ then the set Y where p(x) = 0 is dense

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm studying for a Master's admission exam and I came across this question:

**Let $p : [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ integrable, with $p(x) \ge 0,$ for every $x \in [a, b]$. If $\int_{a}^{b} p(x)dx = 0,$ then the set $Y = \{x \mid p(x) = 0\}$ is dense in $[a, b]$.**

I saw that you already asked about this question here (I can't put the link) and they talked about using measurement theory. I could not understand the solutions presented, so I would like to try to present a solution. I don't have any knowledge about Measure Theory.

Suppose that $Y$ is not dense in $[a, b]$. Then there exists a point $\alpha \in [a, b]$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that

$$(\alpha - \varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon) \ \cap \ Y = \emptyset.$$

Let $[\beta_1, \beta_2] \subset (\alpha - \varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon) \subset [a, b].$ Then

$$ [\beta_1, \beta_2]\ \cap \ Y = \emptyset.$$

**We say that $f$ is Riemann-integrable iff the set of points of discontinuities of f has measure zero.**

Since $p$ is integrable and $[a, b]$ don't have measure zero, $p$ it must be continuous at at least one point $x \in [a, b]$. Again, let's assume that $p$ is discontinuous at all points in the interval  $(\alpha - \varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon)$. Then $p$ is discontinuous in $[\beta_1, \beta_2]$. But $p$ is integrable in $[\beta_1, \beta_2]$ and $[\beta_1, \beta_2]$ has non-zero measure, wich is a contradiction.

Therefore, there must be some point $y \in $ $[\beta_1, \beta_2]$ where $p$ is continuous. Note that $p(y) > 0$. Soon

$$\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} p(x)dx > 0.$$

Following that

$$\int_{a}^{b} p(x)dx = \int_{a}^{\beta_1} p(x)dx + \int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} p(x)dx + \int_{\beta_2}^{b} p(x)dx$$

$$\Rightarrow 0 = \int_{a}^{\beta_1} p(x)dx + \int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} p(x)dx + \int_{\beta_2}^{b} p(x)dx$$

which again is a contradiction, since $\int_{a}^{\beta_1} p(x)dx, \int_{\beta_2}^{b} p(x)dx \geq 0 $.

I really believe this solution is wrong. That's why I'm presenting in the hope that someone can help me improve. All the solutions that were presented were quite sophisticated and either used measurement theory or were difficult for me. **I believe that the error of my solution is when I say that there is a point $y$ where p is continuous.**

Comment: I think you want to replace $\beta_b$ with just $b$ in the limits of integration in the various integrals in the second half of your proof.

Comment: @MW Yes, it was a typo. Already fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: have updated this answer based on the discussion below.]

There is one issue with your proof.  The problem is not that you said there is a point $y$ where $p$ is continuous - that much is in fact true.  However, you then directly jumped from that and the fact that $p(y)>0$ to conclude that $\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2}p(x)\,dx>0$.  This requires a little bit of justification.  Namely, use continuity to argue that there is a neighborhood $[c,d]$ of $y$ on which $p(x)>p(y)/2$ for each $x\in[c,d]$, and then you have $$\int_c^dp(x)\,dx\geq (d-c)p(y)/2>0\text{.}$$
You can then argue similarly to how you have done.

As an aside, once you do get exposed to it, elementary measure theory is indeed helpful here, as it will allow you to argue that the set $[a,b]\backslash Y=\{x:p(x)>0\}$ can be written as a union $\bigcup_{n}\{x:p(x)>1/n\}$, and as each of those sets must have measure $0$, (otherwise you can easily bound integral away from $0$), their (countable) union must have measure $0$ as well.  Then you observe that a set of measure $0$ must have empty interior, and hence a dense complement.

Comment: p is integrable in the Riemann sense. Sorry about that.

Comment: In your problem statement it merely says "Let $p : [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ integrable", I don't see where it says $p$ is "Riemann" integrable.

Comment: Furthermore, I would be very surprised if a problem specified Riemann integrability here, since it is an unnecessarily strong assumption and leads one down the wrong path to prove it.

Comment: This question was taken from a Brazilian book on real analysis that does not deal with measurement theory. The book deals with basic concepts and does not mention, for example, the lebesgue integral, measurable spaces, etc. It is precisely this book that the place where I want to do my master's requires as a bibliography for the test.

Comment: I see, I will update my answer to reflect, and I apologize for my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what we can do within the theory of Riemann integral.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\int_a^b p(x) d x = 0$, there exists $\delta> 0$ such that for every division of the interval $[a,b]$ of norm $\le \delta$, and every intermediate point system $\xi_i$, we have for the Riemann sum

$$ S(f,  \Delta, \xi) < \epsilon$$

Now consider the Darboux sum associated to $f$ and $\Delta$. From the above we get

$$\bar S(f, \Delta) \le \epsilon$$

Now, take any $M > 0$. Consider those intervals $I_k$ of $\Delta$ such that $\sup f\ge M$ on the interval. We have from the above ( since $f\ge 0$)

$$M \cdot \sum \ell (I_k) \le \epsilon$$

so
$$\sum \ell (I_k) \le \frac{\epsilon}{M}$$

We conclude the following: for every $M > 0$, and every $\epsilon'> 0$ there exists a finite covering of the set $\{x \in [a,b] \  f(x) \ge M\}$ by a family of intervals with total sum $\le \epsilon'$.

Now it is the moment for the Lebesgue theory: for take $m = \frac{1}{n}$ and a family $\mathcal{I}_n$ of intervals covering the set
$$\{x \in [a,b] \mid \ f(x) \ge \frac{1}{n}\}$$ of total length
$\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.  We now see that $\{x \ | \ f(x) > 0\}$ can be covered by a countable family of intervals of total length $< \epsilon$.  Now one should check that such a family cannot cover an interval of length $\ge \epsilon$.   This is a fairly subtle result that lies at the beginning of Lebesgue measure theory ( uses compactness of bounded close intervals).

Note: it is perhaps useful to try to stay with the Riemann integral theory as long as possible, and then  see why some (new) results appearing ( the exterior measure) make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The proof can be based on elementary Riemann integral theory, with no use of advanced results. Just bare hands. In particular the notion of the sets of measure zero is not applied.
We do not use the property of continuity of $f$ at some points.

It suffices to show that if $f\ge0$ and $\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,dx =0$ then $f$ must vanish at some point in $[a,b].$ Indeed we can apply the above to any subinterval of $[a,b],$ hence the set of zeros will be dense.

In order to prove the first statement above, WLOG we may assume that $f$ is bounded by $1.$
If $ \int\limits_c^df(x)\,dx=0$ then for fixed $k$ there is a  partition such that the upper Darboux sum is less than $(d-c)/k,$ i.e.
$$\sum_{j=1}^mM_j\Delta x_j<{d-c\over k}$$ where $M_j$ denotes the least upper bound of $f$ on the $j$-th interval of the partition and $\Delta x_j$ is the length of $j$th interval.
Then $M_j<1/k$ for some $j.$ We may assume that the partition is as fine as we wish, in particular finer than $(d-c)/2.$

We are going to construct the sequence of intervals $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ such that $I_{n+1}\subset I_n,$  $|I_{n+1}|\le {1\over 2}|I_n|$ and $f(x)\le {1\over n}$ on $I_n.$ We start with $I_1=[a,b].$ Basing on the  part above for $k=2$ there is such a subinterval $I_2.$ In the same way there is subinterval $I_3$ satisfying the requirements by applying the part above with $k=3.$ We can continue that procedure obtaining the sequence of intervals $I_n.$ The intersection of $I_n$ is a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0,$ as $f(x_0)<{1\over n}$ for every $n.$ $\square $